# How can I fix Face Recognition operands error?

Tags: python, face-recognition

import face_recognition
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

burak_image= face_recognition.load_image_file("C:/Users/EMRE/Desktop/codfacerecog-master/codfacerecog-master/recognize/friends2/burak1.jpg")
burak_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(burak_image)

cansu_image= face_recognition.load_image_file("C:/Users/EMRE/Desktop/codfacerecog-master/codfacerecog-master/recognize/friends2/cansu1.jpg")
cansu_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(cansu_image)

elif_image= face_recognition.load_image_file("C:/Users/EMRE/Desktop/codfacerecog-master/codfacerecog-master/recognize/friends2/elif2.jpg")
elif_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(elif_image)

mert_image= face_recognition.load_image_file("C:/Users/EMRE/Desktop/codfacerecog-master/codfacerecog-master/recognize/friends2/mert2.jpg")
mert_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(mert_image)

merve_image= face_recognition.load_image_file("C:/Users/EMRE/Desktop/codfacerecog-master/codfacerecog-master/recognize/friends2/merve1.jpg")
merve_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(merve_image)

known_face_encodings = [
burak_face_encoding,
cansu_face_encoding,
elif_face_encoding,
mert_face_encoding,
merve_face_encoding

]
known_face_names = [
"BURAK",
"CANSU",
"ELIF" ,
"MERT" ,
"MERVE"

]

image = face_recognition.load_image_file("C:/Users/EMRE/Desktop/codfacerecog-master/codfacerecog-master/recognize/friends2/friends2.jpg")

face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)
face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(image, face_locations)

pil_image = Image.fromarray(image)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_image)

for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):
name = "UNKNOWN"

```
for i,f in enumerate(known_face_encodings):
    matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(f, face_encoding)
    if True in matches:
        name = known_face_names[i]
        break

if True in matches:
    first_match_index = matches.index(True)
    name = known_face_names[first_match_index]


draw.rectangle(((left, top), (right, bottom)), outline=(0, 0, 255))


text_width, text_height = draw.textsize(name)
draw.rectangle(((left, bottom - text_height - 10), (right, bottom)), fill=(48, 63, 159), outline=(48, 63, 159))
draw.text((left + 6, bottom - text_height - 5), name, fill=(255, 255, 255, 0))
```

del draw

pil_image.show()
pil_image
pil_image.save("image_with_boxes.jpg")

MY PROBLEM IS that It shows only one person's name on identified faces.It only shows first known_face_names("BURAK")shows only one person's name on all identified faces; tags of identified people with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://face-recognition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/face_recognition.html#face_recognition.api.compare_faces), `face_recognition.compare_faces` should be able to take an array as the first parameter - but as far as I can tell, it should be the array returned by `face_recognition.face_encodings`. To use multiple images, loop through the array:

```
# note - not indexing the array with [0]
annem_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(annem_image)
babam_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(babam_image)
elif_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(elif_image)

....

for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):
    name = "UNKNOWN"
    # Use a loop to compare to each known face
    for i,f in enumerate(known_face_encodings):
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(f, face_encoding)
        if True in matches:
            name = known_face_names[i]
            break

     # draw rectangle stuff.....
```

Also note, you have an extra comma at the end of

```
elif_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(elif_image) [0],
```

Full code:

```
import face_recognition
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

annem_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("C:/Users/EMRE/Desktop/codfacerecog-master/codfacerecog-master/recognize/images/annem1.jpg")
annem_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(annem_image)

babam_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("C:/Users/EMRE/Desktop/codfacerecog-master/codfacerecog-master/recognize/images/babam1.jpg")
babam_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(babam_image)

elif_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("C:/Users/EMRE/Desktop/codfacerecog-master/codfacerecog-master/recognize/images/elif1.jpg")
elif_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(elif_image)

known_face_encodings = [
    annem_face_encoding,
    babam_face_encoding,
    elif_face_encoding
]
known_face_names = [
    "ANNEM",
    "BABAM",
    "ELIF"
]

image = face_recognition.load_image_file("C:/Users/EMRE/Desktop/codfacerecog-master/codfacerecog-master/recognize/images/family.jpg")
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)
face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(image, face_locations)

pil_image = Image.fromarray(image)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_image)

for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):
    name = "UNKNOWN"
    for i,f in enumerate(known_face_encodings):
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(f, face_encoding)
        if True in matches:
            name = known_face_names[i]
            break

    draw.rectangle(((left, top), (right, bottom)), outline=(48, 63, 159))

    text_width, text_height = draw.textsize(name)
    draw.rectangle(((left, bottom - text_height - 10), (right, bottom)), fill=(48, 63, 159), outline=(48, 63, 159))
    draw.text((left + 6, bottom - text_height - 5), name, fill=(255, 255, 255, 0))


del draw

pil_image.show()
pil_image
```

Comment: Greate but <'..compare_faces(f, face_encoding)' f shoud be a list. So the godd way is '...compare_faces([f], face_encoding)'

Comment: @Bohdan `face_encodings()` returns a list and that is being passed as the first parameter. Note I removed OPs indexing of the result of `face_encodings()`.

Comment: Oh, yes exactly. His <known_face_encodings> is the list of the lists already

Comment: but right now,, it puts the same name tag on all the faces I define, even though I've added different names. How can I fix it?

Comment: @ms.bigdatax Maybe you copied it wrong - it works ok for me. I have updated the answer with a full working program you can copy and try.

Comment: I've just edited my post. I ran the same codes with a different image and added more than one person, but it shows the same name on all defined faces (only "BURAK"). How can I solve this issue? I did not get any error thanks to your edit but my output image does not give right output.

Comment: @ms.bigdatax First, you shouldn't modify your question like that - it invalidates existing answers. Second, compare my code to yours. You have an extra `if True in matches:...` block that is causing all the names to be the same.

Comment: Oppsss sorry i really didn't know. I've  thought if I add new question you might not see it. :(  Yes, I've just updated my codes and I've removed extra "if True in matches:..." code, and it works! I can't thank you enough :)

Comment: Right now I tried pic which includes 12 people face I got this:
  File "C:\Users\EMRE\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 128, in getsize
    return self.font.getsize(text)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0130' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)

Comment: Actually I've just shared this error in my new question.

Answer (score 1):

As I umderstood your error rises from here:

```
matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
```

The message ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (128,) means that `face_encodings` has dimension 3 (it isn't normal for a dlib face encoding but ok for the list) and `face_to_compare` has dimension 128 (it is normal dlib face encoding's dimension).

I can't see from your code above where the problem is.. So, try to `print(known_face_encodings)`  to check if the list really containes that encodings.